# Unable to schedule a C# .exe file to run using Windows task scheduler

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, c#-2.0

I have created a windows application using C# in visual studio 2005. I hav got windows 7 on my machine. Now I am trying to run this .exe file using windows task scheduler but my .exe file needs one .ico file and one.img file associated with it.

So I added these files using syntax -a"file-name" -a"file-name" in the Add Arguments(optional) part.

My task has been scheduled properly but windows is giving me an error that "File.exe has stopped working"

Can anybody suggest me something to correct m error?

Comment: Solved my problem my following below post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Do both the .ico and .img files exist in the same directory as the .exe?
What does the Windows error event log show for your application; if nothing then I'd suggest placing a try/catch around your application's entry point and writing the complete error message.  See class System.Diagnostics.EventLog and the WriteEntry() or WriteEvent() methods for a means to place items in the log.