# Writing a simple two command CMD batch file for task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, cmd, admin

I am having an issue with the new version of Tableau 9.0.1 where I need to run tabadmin cleanup daily or else several gigabites of data will be stored on my server slowing things down and often leading to crashes if not taken care of regularly.

Can someone help me write a batch file script to accomplish the following commands that can be run every morning using task scheduler to avoid future issues?

Tableau is said to be releasing a patch fix from this issue in 9.1.0 but it is an issue we are dealing with currently.

Scripts to run:

cd C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\9.0\bin

tabadmin cleanup

---

I would appreciate anyone's help who is familiar with writing batch files.

Thank you,

Connor

Comment: Those aren't scripts. They're just commands. Put them in a text file, name it `cleanup.cmd`, and save it. Now your commands are a script (batch file). Schedule the script to run in Task Scheduler.

Comment: And you'll want to read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler

Comment: The commands work if I open the batch file myself. If the task scheduler opens it I receive the error (0x1) and it does not work.  I am wondering if it is closing the commands immediately after opening rather than letting the commands clean up the server as needed.    Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

what if you put in a sleep in it and put in in the startup folder?

so when the server starts it would run to file and in the file you can have sleep X amount of seconds then it can run them. then if you have that in a loop you can have it clean every say 12 hours or 24 hours. then if you lose power or a restart it will just run again.