# Batch file to have administrator right without keying in second time password

Tags: batch-file

How do i let **normal user** to open & run batch file as i'm doing restart print spool-er for printer issue. As i can't let them have the administrator password,how can i make the batch file to have administrator rights?
 Thanks
-edit

Using windows 8.1

Comment: This question could be answered on http://superuser.com. Don't forget to tell which OS you use.

Comment: Do you want your **normal user** can restart _print spool-er_ even they don't have administrator privilege or password? If it is so, you can setup a task in task scheduler and run it as administrator. You can find more information in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler)

Comment: Hi ty for the reply, heinz- i want my normal user can restart print spooler even they don't have the administrator priviledge. but do i need to only run administrator 1st time or? cause if got any printer issue i just want them to click the batch file and let the spooler restart so i don't have to go down to their PC. thanks