# Bat file run fine Manually but not in task scheduler

Tags: java, batch-file

I have created a Java Program and also created an Executable jar file and store it in the same folder. In this folder, I have other documents such as log4j.properties and a some a log file housekeep.log. My main.java is stored under the src folder. I also created a bat file, which is running fine when I fire it manually. However, when I am trying to run it on a task scheduler, I cannot read the housekeep.log and also the log4j.properties and it gave me an Access is deined error. `java.io.FileNotFoundExecption:housekeep.log <Access is Deined>` . How can I fix this issue?

Here is my code for my bat file.

```
@echo off
java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar C:\Users\admin\workspace\housekeep\housekeep.jar -o true
PAUSE
```

Comment: sounds like a problem concerning users and the corresponding rights. What os are you using? In case of windows try to start the task as the same user as in the interactive session.

Comment: I am using windows, the one that work is I tried to use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler as an example by adding an argument, but I thought there are code that can actually do that.

Comment: Task scheduler runs your `bat` script under another working directory, I guess `%windir%\system32`. Switch to right one using `pushd "%~dp0"` command (or `cd /D %~dp0`)