# Schedule a script developed in Anaconda via Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to use Windows Task Scheduler to run a script in python and write a csv file. I've always used Anaconda,
so I don't understand how Python's command line works. If I run this on Spyder,

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
now_is = pd.DataFrame(['Now is '+ str(datetime.datetime.now())])
now_is.to_csv('C:/Users/camila/now_is.csv')
```

it works perfectly. But Task Scheduler executes this .py using the command terminal, where this code won't work.
I guess I need to install pandas again, but I can't even get pip to work on this...

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pip
>>> pip.__version__
'9.0.1'

>>> pip install pandas
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pandas
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

- How can I schedule a script developed in Anaconda on Windows Task Scheduler?
- How can I import the modules that I have in Anaconda in the command line?

Comment: The title contradicts the question. Which one to answer -- how to schedule a script or how to run a shell command from Python console?

Comment: To install something with `pip` on Windows, you should run it in the Windows console (sometimes called the command-line prompt) — **not** from the Python console.

Comment: Should it be "How can I schedule a script developed in Anaconda on Windows Task Scheduler?" ? I'm super new in python so I confuse the terinology @ivan_pozdeev

Comment: Where you developed the script isn't relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a python script in virtual environment from windows task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622514/run-a-python-script-in-virtual-environment-from-windows-task-scheduler)

Answer (score 24):

Follow these instructions:

- Create a bat file.
- Then add this code:

```
@ECHO OFF 
TITLE Execute python script on anaconda environment
ECHO Please Wait...
:: Section 1: Activate the environment.
ECHO ============================
ECHO Conda Activate
ECHO ============================
@CALL "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" TestEnvironment
:: Section 2: Execute python script.
ECHO ============================
ECHO Python test.py
ECHO ============================
python C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Test\test.py

ECHO ============================
ECHO End
ECHO ============================

PAUSE
```

Ref [Run a python script in virtual environment from windows task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622514/run-a-python-script-in-virtual-environment-from-windows-task-scheduler)

Comment: Thanks!! This worked. Note for other users, change `"TestEnvironment"` to your desired env, ie, what you type for `f"conda activate {TestEnvironment}"`... ha. (obviously my comment is a little facetious using f-strings and makes no sense, but I hope the logic helps a little).

Answer (score 0):

To use `pip`, you need to run it from the Windows Command Prompt, `CMD.EXE`. It should show up if you type `cmd` at the Start menu.

When you go to schedule a Python script, use the "create a basic task" wizard (the full version is needlessly complicated), set the action to "start a program," the program to run as `python.exe`, and put the script's path and arguments in the arguments box.

Answer (score 0):

to add to @Nag, it took me quite a while, do find out that the default anaconda environment is simply "base".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30303951)