# How to schedule a python script to run from virtual environment via task scheduler

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I stumbled on an answer for basically the exact same question, but either I am implementing the solution wrong, the solution is no longer accurate, or some other issue is at play.

[Run a python script in virtual environment from windows task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622514/run-a-python-script-in-virtual-environment-from-windows-task-scheduler)

I used the code from above link, edited for my directories, and copied directly into the task scheduler program/script prompt.

```
C:\Users\I511843\myenv\activate.bat && python C:\Users\I511843\Desktop\Atom_scripts\test.py
```

I then set the program to run every time I unlocked the machine. The program simply writes a text file called test.txt containing the text "success!"

The text file populates in the correct directory when I run from the command line, however, the program doe snot execute from the task scheduler.

Comment: Virtual environments don't have to be activated. Directly run the fully-qualified path to "python.exe" in the environment. There's no need for a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the commands in a batch file and executing the batch file from task scheduler? Something like below:

`C:\Users\I511843\myenv\activate.bat && python C:\Users\I511843\Desktop\Atom_scripts\test.py` goes into task.bat file.

In task scheduler, run `task.bat` from cmd.

Comment: I tried this, which was a step in the right direction, but I believe there are still errors in the code snippet above. For example, there might be an issue in `activate.bat && python` - I'm not sure what `.bat` does in the context of a batch file. Likewise, I would think that python still requires a full path, vice just calling `python`.

Comment: activate.bat would activate your python virtual environment. As per `python`, make sure you have python path added in your environment variables. Nevertheless, do you mind commenting what error you got after following this approach ?