# running a batch file on win 7 *all the time*

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a batch file ( a watch dog that checks if the web site isup and running ) and now I need to make sure that it runs all the time.

When I remote desktop to my server, and start the .bat file manualy, and stay logged-in, it is OK. But when I log out from the server, or when I log out from the remote desktop, the show is over - which means there goes my watch dog.

I just need to make sure that that particular .bat file to run all the time.

How do we achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a batch file with Windows task scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to give more definitive answer without seen the batch script. Try starting the batch automatically at certain time on the server from *Task Scheduler*, and carefully select all relevant Task options. Experiment with these options to achieve the desired output, and let me know.