# i need to make a batch file run every few seconds. How do i do it?

Tags: batch-file, automation, ftp

im on Windows 10. I want my script to run every few seconds or, if even possible, every second. I need it so i can get Every Picture on my FTP Server as soon as possible without any delay

I have tried to do it with task scheduler, but the fastest i can do is every 5 Minutes

```
Administrator
Pw123
cd Kamera-1
lcd C:\xampp\htdocs\website\Bilder\Kamera-1
binary
mget *.jpg
mdel *.jpg
bye
```

Here is my Script. The first 2 Lines are the Logins to my FTP Server and the rest is just to get the files and then delete the files on the ftp, so i dont download it twice

Comment: Frame Challenge:  If all you are doing is Syncing files/folders, then perhaps consider using a File-Syncing program, such as WinSCP, AOMEI, WebDrive, or SyncBack.  Also, since this is about **scheduling** and not **code**, it might be a better fit on [su] instead of [so]

Comment: See [Run a batch file with Windows task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4437701/850848).

Comment: Speaking from experience, a batch script that runs every second will slam your CPU and make your computer unusable. Look into folder synchronization software instead.

Answer (score 0):

*To answer your literal question:* Just loop your code in the batch file, with a short delay:

```
:start

<your code here>

timeout 5

goto start
```

---

*Though as said in the comments, there are better ways to achieve what you want.*